# Como mostrar dados de duas tabelas em c#?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, orm

eu construí uma webservice em c#. Com uma tabela ficou fácil ara exibir mas e se eu tiver duas tabelas como ficaria para eu exibir esses dado? eu fiz assim que é a forma mais fácil:

```
 [WebMethod]
     public String Teste()
     {
       SqlConnection Con = null;

       Mulheres_Cont contato= null;
       List<Object> contatos = new List<Object>();
       Con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["treinamentoBase"].ConnectionString);
       Con.Open();
       String Select = @"select tb_contato.nome, tb_contato.senha, tb_contato.usuario, tb_mulheres.nome, tb_mulheres.formacao from tb_contato inner join tb_mulheres on tb_contato.id = tb_mulheres.id";
       SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(Select, Con);
       SqlDataReader Dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
       while(Dr.Read())
       {

           contato = new Mulheres_Cont();

           contato.nome = Dr.GetString(0);
           contato.senha = Dr.GetString(1);
           contato.usuario = Dr.GetString(2);
           contato.nomeM = Dr.GetString(3);
           contato.formacao = Dr.GetString(4);

           contatos.Add(contato);

       }
       Con.Close();
       JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();

       return json.Serialize(contatos);
    }
```

eu acho que existe outra forma mais elegante para exibir isso alguém poderia me informar?

Tipo eu criei a tabela só para representar esses dados para serem exibidos em formato json:

```
public class Mulheres_Cont
{
    public String nome { get; set; }
    public String senha { get; set; }
    public String usuario { get; set; }
    public String nomeM { get; set; }
    public String formacao { get; set; }
}
```

Teria uma forma mais elegante de fazer isso? Eu sei que eu poderia criar uma classe Mulher :

```
   public class Mulher
   {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Contato idContato { get; set; }
    public String nome { get; set; }
    public String formacao { get; set; }

    }
```

E essa classe é de um relacionamento de 1 : N ou seja um contato pode ter muitas mulheres.

Mas desse jeito eu não consegui fazer alguém me dá uma luz de como faz desse jeito? Com uma agregação?

Comment: você deseja exibir um objeto `mulher` e dentro dele uma **lista** de `mulher_cont`???

Comment: Desse jeito está funcionando. tipo ele está retornan os dados mas eu criei uma classe chamada Mulheres_Cont que é um inner join com duas tabelas que existem no banco SQL SERVER que são tb_contato e tb_mulheres. E criei uma classe no c# que é a Mulheres_Cont somente para exibir esses dados

Comment: Ok. Deu certo. Mas acho que tem uma outra forma de se fazer isso e gostaria de saber como faz.

Comment: eu queria fazer de outra forma exemplo queria instanciar a classe Mulher e a classe contato. E fazer algo como:  public class Mulher
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public Contato idContato { get; set; }
        public String nome { get; set; }
        public String formacao { get; set; }
        
    }

Comment: Eu ainda não entendi @gonz como você quer exibir?

Comment: Um contato pode TER muitas mulheres ou pode estar associado a muitas mulheres? A classe Mulher é que pode ter vários Contatos não? Ou seja, a classe mulher tem uma IList<Contato> internamente. Entendi assim, é isso mesmo?

Comment: Vc quer retornar uma lista de "Contato", em que cada contato, tenha uma lista de "Mulher"? A propósito, estranhas essas entidades, é sistema pra que?

Comment: Um sistema só para eu aprender mesmo para exibir de outra forma. Como faz para eu inserir uma chave estrangeira na tabela Mulher?

Um Contato pode ter várias Mulheres. Faz de conta que é contato é um homem. Um homem pode ter várias mulheres

Comment: eu incluo todos na lista e mando retornar. Entende?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Contato
{
    public String nome { get; set; }
    public String senha { get; set; }
    public String usuario { get; set; }

    ///<summary>
    /// Contém uma lista de mulheres
    ///</summary>
    public List<Mulher> mulheres {get; set; }    
}

public class Mulher
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Contato idContato { get; set; }
    public String nome { get; set; }
    public String formacao { get; set; }

}


while(Dr.Read())
{

    contato = new Contato();

    contato.nome = Dr.GetString(0);
    contato.senha = Dr.GetString(1);
    contato.usuario = Dr.GetString(2);

    //Irá adicionar um novo objeto a lista de mulheres em contato
    contato.mulheres = new List<Mulher>();
    contato.mulheres.Add(new Mulher
    {
        nome = Dr.GetString(3),
        formacao = Dr.GetString(4) 
    });

    contatos.Add(contato);

}
```

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo mas e a consulta para exibir como ficaria?

Comment: Nessa parte: while(Dr.Read())
       {

           contato = new Mulheres_Cont();

           contato.nome = Dr.GetString(0);
           contato.senha = Dr.GetString(1);
           contato.usuario = Dr.GetString(2);
           contato.nomeM = Dr.GetString(3);
           contato.formacao = Dr.GetString(4);

           contatos.Add(contato);

       }
       Con.Close(); Como ficaria

Comment: Deixa eu fazer aqui...

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas acredito que seja isso que você queria, alterei o código.

Comment: dá erro nessa parte: contato.mulheres = new Mulher
{
    nome = Dr.GetString(3),
    formacao = Dr.GetString(4) 
};

Comment: Desse jeito, vai repetir o contato pelo número de mulheres que o mesmo possui.

Comment: Sim, concordo com você @FBatista, mas eu precisa primeiro entende se era isso que ele queria.

Comment: @EdvaldoFarias pelo que eu entendi, quer enviar uma lista de contatos, com uma lista de mulheres em cada, só não entendi a questão de quando ele pergunta como exibir, afinal é um ws... eu faria carregando em uma lista geral com todos os campos e depois com uma consulta linq eu agruparia por contato. Ou, mais fácil, fazer com Dapper.

Comment: desculpa @gonz está errado mesmo. É assim que deve ser: contato.mulheres = new List<Mulher>(); e depois contato.mulheres.Add(new Mulher { ... } );

Comment: Ai meu Deeeeeus que difícil!!!!

Comment: Deu ceeeeerto, Meu Deus.